# How to add the data from Google Chrome Extension's Console.log to my current browser's page console?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, console.log

This is regarding a Google Chrome Extension which I am trying to build.

My aim here is to Fetch the data using AJAX and get the data in the console tab.

So, I am able to get the data using AJAX and get it in the console tab but that's in the console tab of my Chrome Extension.

I would like to add that same data to my current browsers window's console. So how to do that?

Basically, I have the data in my Chrome Extension's console tab, just want to have or pass that same data in my browser's current window, so that in my current window, when I open my console, it should have that data.

Do I need to add anything in my Manifest.json file?

So for example, using my Extension, if I click on Inspect and then console, I get "Some Message which is fetched using AJAX" in my console tab.

I want the same message - "Some Message which is fetched using AJAX" in my browser's current window's console.

Comment: You can't- they run in separate containers. If this was possible, it would be very insecure.

Comment: You can. Simply use chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: \`console.log(${JSON.stringify(yourData)})\`}) or use messaging and a content script.

Comment: So, basically, this is my JS file -

`var buttonClick = document.getElementById('bt1');
buttonClick.addEventListener('click', loadDoc('https://abcd/ef/Script1', myFunction));

function loadDoc(url, cFunction) {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
      cFunction(this);

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xhttp) {
 
}`

So, I should add the chrome.tabs... here in this JS file?

Comment: Yes, but only if you want to.

Comment: @wOxxOm When I do that, I get the error - "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access a chrome:// URL"

Comment: It means your current tab is the empty new tab page. Extensions can't run scripts there. Switch to a normal web page tab.